# How to work around ebook-convert.exe (in calibre portable) halting batch file execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-vista, calibre

I use ebook-convert.exe from a batch file, and on one of my machines (old Windows vista laptop), any calls ebook-convert.exe prevent further commands in a batch file from running (in that .bat file, or in that cmd shell instance for instance). The conversion to .mobi actually succeeds, prints no errors even in -v -v full verbose mode. I tried versions 1.20.0 and 0.9.6 of calibre portable. It seems to be related to the executable itself, and not to the specific conversion job (just running it with -h flag has same effect). I tried running cmd in administrator mode, wrapping it with 'call' command, nothing helps. Assuming the calibre issue is a black hole that can't be solved, is there a DOS trick I could possibly try to keep batch commands running no matter what odd thing happens with ebook-convert.exe on that machine?

Comment: Try calling it with the start command

Comment: thanks, that works around the batch file completely halting, but it also does not wait for the program to complete, so further steps can't rely on the output of ebook-convert.exe, requiring more workarounds... still leaves me better off than before ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `call` in a batch file should work on normal console programs but it is possible for programs to "escape" if they really want to.

Using `Start` instead might work but it does not wait by default and its syntax is not sane:

```
 Start /B /WAIT c:\path\without\spaces.exe optionalParameter
```

or

```
 Start "" /B /WAIT "c:\path\w i t h\spaces.exe" optionalParameter
```

Remove `/B` to run the application in a new console.

Another option is to call `ping localhost` and `For` (to get the file size with `%%~zA`) in a loop until the size of the destination file stops increasing. This is a bit of a hack and might not work, it depends on how the converter opens the file and how often it flushes the writes.

Comment: ah, the /B and /WAIT flags look really promising, will try it out